# How to deal with bad proxies with Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to make a webscraper. I get a proxylist online then I check the list and delete non working proxies. But while my scraper is running some of them are getting blocked by the website or proxy dies fully. How can I delete bad proxies from my list? I tried to `proxies.remove(proxy)` in a for loop but it says size of the list changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a python list... You could make a basic get request at the start and check for an error by doing something like

```
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == (the bad error code you are getting ex. 404); 
    proxies.remove(proxy)
    print(f"Removed {proxy}")
```

... It appears the reason this is not working because you are not checking for anything in the for loop and are just removing the proxies.